# RaisedButton stays null

Tags: flutter

Im trying to do a register page and everything is working but the logic for the onpressed property. This is my code:

```
onPressed: _usernameController.text == "" || _emailController.text == "" || _passwordController.text == "" || _passController.text == "" ? null : () {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });
  register(_usernameController.text, _emailController.text, _passwordController.text, _passController.text);
}
```

the button stays null even if you fill all the required fields as if the condition remained true. I know the code is right because I have a similar logic in my login page, and also whenever I refresh with the fields already full it magically lights up the button and everything works. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please check my answer hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Form](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation) widget. Form widget has onChange property also you can listen to all states. Form widget has other property, the key is validated and control your form state. Don't forget must be declared validator property.

Same example:
[image]

Full code: [Form Validattor](https://gist.github.com/VB10/3662764fcac269dbd7de0a1286e27d8a)

Answer (score 0):

Please make one method like below..

```
void _registration(){
 //add register code here instead of write at onPressed event
}
```

and call this method in onPressed event like this...

```
onPressed: _registration
```